# Java Security: KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry unable to fetch key stored using keytool -genseckey command

Tags: java, keystore, keytool, secret-key, java-security

I am facing an issue while trying to fetch the secret key entry from a keystore, created to store the password for a service account.

My **keytool** command reads as below:

```
keytool -genseckey -alias securesvc -keyalg AES -keysize 256 -keystore myseckey.jceks -storetype JCEKS -storepass myseckey
```

Next, I am trying to extract the key for **securesvc** using **KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry**:

```
1  String keystorePath = "security/myseckey.jceks";
2  char[] keystorePass = "myseckey".trim().toCharArray();
3  KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(new File(keystorePath), keystorePass);
4  try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(keystorePath)) {
5   ks.load(fis, keystorePass);
6  }
7  KeyStore.ProtectionParameter pp = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(keystorePass);
8  KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry ske = (SecretKeyEntry) ks.getEntry("securesvc", pp);
9  SecretKey sk = ske.getSecretKey();
10 String securedKey = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(sk.getEncoded()));
```

But, I keep getting the exception below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.KeyProtector.unseal(KeyProtector.java:399)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.JceKeyStore.engineGetKey(JceKeyStore.java:146)
    at java.base/java.security.KeyStoreSpi.engineGetEntry(KeyStoreSpi.java:499)
    at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.getEntry(KeyStore.java:1548)
    at com.practice.TestClass.getSecretKey(TestClass.java:8)
```

Can anyone point out where I am possibly going wrong here, and suggest a solution?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your last line is wrong because keys in a keystore are not in base64 -- `getEncoded()` is really for a _format_ like PKCS8 not a true encoding, and for AES is just raw bytes -- and moreover are not characters that can be stored in `String`. However the exception you are getting on line 8 should not occur (and does not for me, in 11.0.11 and 17.0.2) unless you answered the keytool prompt for 'Enter key password' with something other than return.

Comment: Yes, I had entered the value "securesvc" when prompted later as that is the secret password that I need to store.
Also, I need to capture the key password to be passed to another program, how do I convert it to String? I tried converting it as hexadecimal but didn't work that way either.

Comment: The key password is not stored anywhere. The _key_ is stored, encrypted _using_ the key password. You must _supply_ the same key password to retrieve and decrypt the key. The _password_ is normally human-typable and can be handled in a String; the key cannot. If by 'program' you mean a separate process, in general you can't pass a symmetric key to a different process. If you meant other Java code, you often pass either a `[Secret]Key` object or the not-really-encoded `byte[]`, but it varies widely depending on the code which you didn't show or identify.